# Minecraft Forge Modding 1.16.5 - Problem with registering a entity

Tags: java, minecraft-forge

I have set myself the task of creating a working Minecraft mod for Minecraft 1.16.5. Now I try to register a entity. The problem is, the mod loads successfully but if I try to spawn this entity then I get the message "Unknown entity: serverutils:npc". I'm very new at writing a minecraft mod. Can anybody help me at this problem?

Here a the code:

**NpcRenderer(2).java:**

```
package net.themcking.serverutils.entity;

import static net.themcking.serverutils.ServerUtils.MOD_ID;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.EntityRendererManager;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.LivingRenderer;
import net.minecraft.util.ResourceLocation;

public class NpcRenderer2 extends LivingRenderer<NpcEntity, NpcModel<NpcEntity>> {
    
    public static final ResourceLocation texture = new ResourceLocation(MOD_ID, "textures/entity/npc.png");

    public NpcRenderer2(EntityRendererManager manager) {
        super(manager, new NpcModel<>(), 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public ResourceLocation getTextureLocation(NpcEntity p_110775_1_) {
        return texture;
    }
}
```

**NpcModel.java:**

```
package net.themcking.serverutils.entity;

import com.mojang.blaze3d.matrix.MatrixStack;
import com.mojang.blaze3d.vertex.IVertexBuilder;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.model.EntityModel;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.model.ModelRenderer;

public class NpcModel<T extends NpcEntity> extends EntityModel<NpcEntity> {
    private final ModelRenderer head;
    private final ModelRenderer body;
    private final ModelRenderer leftArm;
    private final ModelRenderer rightArm;
    private final ModelRenderer rightLeg;
    private final ModelRenderer leftLeg;

    public NpcModel() {
        head = new ModelRenderer(this);
        head.texOffs(0, 0).addBox(-4.0F, -8.0F, -4.0F, 8.0F, 8.0F, 8.0F, 0.0F, false);
        head.texOffs(32, 0).addBox(-4.0F, -8.0F, -4.0F, 8.0F, 8.0F, 8.0F, 0.5F, false);

        body = new ModelRenderer(this);
        body.texOffs(16, 16).addBox(-4.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 8.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.0F, false);
        body.texOffs(16, 32).addBox(-4.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 8.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.25F, false);

        rightArm = new ModelRenderer(this);
        rightArm.texOffs(40, 16).addBox(-3.0F, -2.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.0F, false);
        rightArm.texOffs(40, 32).addBox(-3.0F, -2.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.25F, false);

        leftArm = new ModelRenderer(this);
        leftArm.texOffs(32, 48).addBox(-1.0F, -2.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.0F, false);
        leftArm.texOffs(48, 48).addBox(-1.0F, -2.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.25F, false);

        rightLeg = new ModelRenderer(this);
        rightLeg.texOffs(0, 16).addBox(-2.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.0F, false);
        rightLeg.texOffs(0, 32).addBox(-2.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.25F, false);

        leftLeg = new ModelRenderer(this);
        leftLeg.texOffs(16, 48).addBox(-2.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.0F, false);
        leftLeg.texOffs(0, 48).addBox(-2.0F, 0.0F, -2.0F, 4.0F, 12.0F, 4.0F, 0.25F, false);

    }

    @Override
    public void setupAnim(NpcEntity p_225597_1_, float p_225597_2_, float p_225597_3_, float p_225597_4_,
        float p_225597_5_, float p_225597_6_) {
    }

    @Override
    public void renderToBuffer(MatrixStack matrixStack, IVertexBuilder buffer, int packedLight, int packedOverlay, float red, float green, float blue, float alpha) {
        head.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
        body.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
        rightArm.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
        leftArm.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
        rightLeg.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
        leftLeg.render(matrixStack, buffer, packedLight, packedOverlay);
    }
}
```

**NpcEntity.java:**

```
package net.themcking.serverutils.entity;

import net.minecraft.entity.EntityType;
import net.minecraft.entity.LivingEntity;
import net.minecraft.inventory.EquipmentSlotType;
import net.minecraft.item.ItemStack;
import net.minecraft.util.HandSide;
import net.minecraft.world.World;

public class NpcEntity extends LivingEntity {
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public NpcEntity(EntityType<? extends LivingEntity> type, World worldin) {
        super((EntityType<? extends LivingEntity>) AllEntities.NPC, worldin);
    }

    @Override
    public Iterable<ItemStack> getArmorSlots() {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ItemStack getItemBySlot(EquipmentSlotType p_184582_1_) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void setItemSlot(EquipmentSlotType p_184201_1_, ItemStack p_184201_2_) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public HandSide getMainArm() {
        return null;
    }

}
```

**AllEntities.java:**

```
package net.themcking.serverutils.entity;
import static net.themcking.serverutils.ServerUtils.MOD_ID;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityClassification;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityType;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.DeferredRegister;
import net.minecraftforge.registries.ForgeRegistries;
public class AllEntities {
    public static final DeferredRegister<EntityType<?>> ENTITY_TYPES = DeferredRegister.create(ForgeRegistries.ENTITIES, MOD_ID);
    
    public static final EntityType<?> NPC = EntityType.Builder.of(NpcEntity::new, EntityClassification.CREATURE).build("serverutils:npc").setRegistryName("npc");
    
}
```

**ServerUtils.java:**

```
package net.themcking.serverutils;

import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.EntityRenderer;
import net.minecraft.client.renderer.entity.EntityRendererManager;
import net.minecraft.entity.EntityType;
import net.minecraftforge.common.MinecraftForge;
import net.minecraftforge.event.RegistryEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.event.entity.EntityAttributeCreationEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.IEventBus;
import net.minecraftforge.eventbus.api.SubscribeEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.IRenderFactory;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.client.registry.RenderingRegistry;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Mod;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLClientSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.lifecycle.FMLCommonSetupEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.event.server.FMLServerStartingEvent;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.javafmlmod.FMLJavaModLoadingContext;

import net.themcking.serverutils.entity.AllEntities;
import net.themcking.serverutils.entity.NpcEntity;
import net.themcking.serverutils.entity.NpcRenderer;
import net.themcking.serverutils.entity.NpcRenderer2;

@Mod("serverutils")
public class ServerUtils {
    
    public static final String MOD_ID = "serverutils";
    
    public ServerUtils() {
        IEventBus bus = FMLJavaModLoadingContext.get().getModEventBus();
        bus.addListener(this::setup);
        bus.addListener(this::clientSetup);

        
        AllEntities.ENTITY_TYPES.register(bus);
        MinecraftForge.EVENT_BUS.register(this);
        

    }
    

    
    private void setup(final FMLCommonSetupEvent event) {
        
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private void clientSetup(final FMLClientSetupEvent event) {
        RenderingRegistry.registerEntityRenderingHandler((EntityType<NpcEntity>) AllEntities.NPC, NpcRenderer2::new);
    }
    
    @SubscribeEvent
    public void onServerStarting(FMLServerStartingEvent event) {
        
    }
    
    @Mod.EventBusSubscriber(bus=Mod.EventBusSubscriber.Bus.MOD)
    public static class RegistryEvents {
        @SubscribeEvent
        public void registerEntities(final RegistryEvent.Register<EntityType<?>> event) {
            event.getRegistry().registerAll(
                AllEntities.NPC
            );
            
        }
    }

}
 }
```

That are all mod classes that I have in my mod.
I hope, some can help me.

p.s: I'm not very good in english

Comment: Your resource location shouldn't have the file extension png as far as I know. "textures/entity/npc.png" can just be "textures/entity/npc" .

Comment: It is not possible that this is the problem I'm having. In your case, I think the result is a texture bug and not the problem what I'm having.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.